# Como transferir array completo do form para outro arquivo PHP?

Tags: php, array

Tenho  este `form` e quero passar o array (tal e qual como está) `$array_dos_pagamentos` para o `recive.php` mas só consigo passar valores únicos. Como posso passar o array completo?

```
<form action='http://www.xxx.com/wp-content/xx/xx/recive.php' method='post'  class="my-form_recibos" target='hidden-form'>
 <label> <input type='checkbox' autocomplete="off" class="" name='enviarmail'    value='yes' >enviar pedido de recibos ?</label>

<input type="hidden" name="result" value="<?php $array_dos_pagamentos); ?>">

  <input type='Submit' value='Salvar'   onclick='saved(<?php echo $fid ?>)' />
</form>
```

O array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [nome] => Claudia Mateus [total] => 20 [email] => claudiamateux@gmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [nome] => Joana Gonçalves [total] => 20 [email] => joanagoncalves95@hotmail.com ) [2] => Array ( [nome] => Paulo Abreu [total] => 20 [email] => pda9891@gmail.com ) )
```

Comment: Da onde vem `$array_dos_pagamentos` não seria melhor separar me outros campos?

Comment: Deve ter solução melhor que essa. Seria legal explicar a necessidade inicial, pois em princípio, se o dado tem que ser reutilizado, provavelmente você já deveria armazenar ele do lado do servidor nem que fosse temporariamente. Ou ao menos manter a estrutura do form original na página seguinte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem duas formas para isso, que conheço.

**Usando JSON (citado pelo @rray):**

> Para o formulário:

```
<?
$json = json_encode($array_dos_pagamentos); 
// Isto ira converter a array em json
?>
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="<?= htmlentities($json, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>">
```

> Para receber os dados:

```
<?
$array = json_decode($_POST['result'], true);
// Isto irá tornar o JSON em array
?>
```

Informações em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

**Usando Serialize + HMAC (ou AES-CGM):**

Se não puder usar o JSON existe uma alternativa não muito recomendada, usando `serialize()`, lembre-se de nunca utilizar `serialize()` sozinho, *vise documentação*.

> Para o formulário:

```
<?

$serialize = serialize($array_dos_pagamentos);
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha384', $serialize, 'SUA_SENHA');

$value = $hmac.$serialize;

?>
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="<?= htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') ?>">
```

> Para receber os dados:

```
$value = $_POST['result'];

$hmac = mb_substr($value, 0, 96, '8bit');
$serialize = mb_substr($value, 96, null, '8bit');

if(hash_equals($hmac, hash_hmac('sha384', $serialize, 'SUA_SENHA'))){
    $array = unserialize($serialize);
}
```

Isso irá prevenir que o valor do input seja alterado pelo usuário, o que é um grande problema ao se utilizar o `serialize()`.

Informações em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php.

Comment: Faltou escapar o dado serializado antes de por no `value=`. O serialize pode ter uma diversidade de caracteres que quebraria o form/input. A começar por aspas.

Comment: Verdade, havia esquecido isso. Vou editar.

Comment: obrigado com Serialize funcionou  a ver. JSON nao deu por algum motivo :)

Answer (score 4):

Nesse caso você pode transformar o array em um json e no `recive.php` voltar ele a sua forma original.

```
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="<?php echo json_encode( $array_dos_pagamentos); ?>">
```

No recive.php fica assim, a função [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php), detectar erros de sintaxe no json, está disponível na versão 5.3 do php e [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) no php5.5

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode($_POST['result'], true) or die(json_last_error());
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($json);
```